Different DbContext instances in my ASP.NET Core application sharing resources or combining queries
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where I have a DbContext instance injected via dependency injection. The context is registered as scoped.
However, I'm experiencing an issue where, when making multiple requests in parallel, the queries from the same context seem to be combining or sharing resources, even though a different instance of the context is supposed to be used for each request.
The context is injected in the constructor:
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataTableFromSqlServerByQuery(string sql)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    
    using (var cmd = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        await context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();

        using (var sqlReader = (SqlDataReader)await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            dt.Load(sqlReader);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}

Sometimes it looks like queries from different HTTP requests are combining into one, and when I check using sp_whoisactive, it shows the second query running for an absurd amount of time (e.g., 100 days), even though it's a new request.
I've checked

That DbContext is registered as scoped, and I have confirmed with logging that each request gets a new instance
I am using MultipleActiveResultSets=True in the connection string

Are there any best practices or things I might be missing that I can do to fix this problem?

Have you tried to Close connection, because you have explictly opened it?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I did try explicitly closing the connection using context.Database.CloseConnectionAsync(), but the first query is still executing when the second one is called so its not closed yet

you need to show more code.  How is this method getting called?  what's the registration code look like?  Off the top of my head you could see this if you create a a singleton instance and pass the dbcontext in the constructor. then that scoped instance is captured by the singleton class.

Good point from previous comment, while lifetime has class which uses DbContext?
